# Data Persistence

Tags: java, json, hash-map, serialization

I was wondering if I could get some feedback on the library I created to persist data online.

**JitterPushDemo.java**

```
public class JitterPushDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Jitter jitter = new Jitter("scores");


        // create hash map to map scores to players

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("Bob", "300");
        map.put("Sam", "500");

        // push data online to jitter object
        jitter.pushData(map);

    }

}
```

**JitterPullDemo.java**

```
public class JitterPullDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Jitter jitter = new Jitter("scores");

        // now pulling data from online and iterating
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> item: jitter.pullData().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Player: " + item.getKey());
            System.out.println("Scores: " + item.getValue());
        }  

    }

}
```

**Source Code**

```
package org.main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Jitter {

    URL location;
    String thing;

    public Jitter(String thing) {
        this.thing = thing;
    }

    private void setLocation(String place) {

        try 
        {
            location = new URL(place);
            location.openConnection();
        }

        catch (Exception e) 
        {

        }

    }

    public String readData() {

        InputStream dataStream = null;
        InputStreamReader read = null;
        String result = ""; int value;

        try 
        {
            dataStream = location.openStream();
            read = new InputStreamReader(dataStream);

            while ((value = read.read()) != -1)
                result += String.valueOf((char) value);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        return result;
    }

    public void pushData(HashMap<String, String> map) {

        String url = "https://dweet.io/dweet/for/" + thing + "?";

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : map.entrySet()) {
            String k = URLEncoder.encode(item.getKey());
            String v = URLEncoder.encode(item.getValue());
            String sub = k + '=' + v + "&"; url += sub;
        }

        try 
        {
            setLocation(url);
        }

        catch (Exception e) 
        {

        }

        readData();

    }

    public void pushData(String key, String value) {
        String url = "https://dweet.io/dweet/for/" + thing + "?";
        setLocation(url + key + "=" + value); readData();
    }

    public String pullData(String key) {

        setLocation("https://dweet.io/get/latest/dweet/for/" + thing);
        JSONArray main = new JSONObject(readData()).getJSONArray("with");
        JSONObject data = ((JSONObject) main.get(0)).getJSONObject("content");

        return data.optString(key);
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> pullData() {

        setLocation("https://dweet.io/get/latest/dweet/for/" + thing);
        JSONArray main = new JSONObject(readData()).getJSONArray("with");
        JSONObject data = ((JSONObject) main.get(0)).getJSONObject("content");

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for (String key : data.keySet()) {
            map.put(key, data.optString(key));
        }

        return map;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FGITW:

### Duplication

```
JSONArray main = new JSONObject(readData()).getJSONArray("with");
JSONObject data = ((JSONObject) main.get(0)).getJSONObject("content");
```

You have the duplicated code block above in a few places, it's probably better to put them in a method.

```
private JSONObject getJSONObject(final String jsonOutput) {
    return ((JSONObject) new JSONObject(jsonOutput).getJSONArray("with").get(0))
        .getJSONObject("content").
}
```

Same goes for the `String` `https://dweet.io`, extract it to a `final` field perhaps?

### Input sanitization?

You are currently constructing your `URL`s directly by appending `thing`. I'm not sure how [dweet](https://dweet.io/) handles *weird* keys<s>/data</s>, but you should consider doing some kind of sanity check here.

### Handling for one or multiple keys/values

I will prefer to convert the arguments to the `pushData(String, String)` method as a `Map` so that I can pass it to the other `pushData(Map)` method. This ensures your URI encoding is handled correctly - as you can see currently you aren't handling that for `pushData(String, String)`. Also, I might be missing something here, but why do you need to `readData()` after pushing data to the web service?

### Don't swallow `Exceptions`

`readData()` does not appear to handle thrown `Exception`s in any meaningful way. Should it log to some console output? Fail fast? Wrap the `Exception` and throw it to the caller?

I'm also not to keen on calling your `InputStreamReader` instance `read`, because `read.read()` sounds... strange. Why not just call it `reader`? And I think you'll need to `close()` it when you're done with it.

### Define variables/parameters with interfaces, not implementations

Just one more thing, it's better to declare `Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();` (>= Java 7 syntax), since your code should not need to be aware of the actual implementation of `map`. Same goes for `public void pushData(Map<String, String> map)`.

Comment: Firstly, thank your for the input. The read data method simply presses request thus adding the key value pairs in queue. Read the dweet documentation or more.

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit...

Comment: Pushing data only occurs when the stream is read from the given URL. Thus I need to do it in all four methods.

Comment: Have you tried the library? Is it useful and does it work as expected?

Comment: If that's the case, you can further combine `setLocation(...); return readData();` into a single method too... ;)

Comment: So is it a good idea for a library? Should I publish it after refining?

Comment: Turning it in a library probably requires you to finalize your APIs, and that's including how `Exception`s are handled. The way I see it, you might want to refine these further... It's your call though, and all the best!

Answer (score 4):

- Off the bat, your code contains no comments. Comments are useful to know what the code does.
- Your code is very ambiguous. What is

  ```
  String thing; // a username?
  ```

  ... it behooves you to name this more descriptively.

  ```
  setLocation()
  ```

  I notice it sets the subdirectory. You can make this more specific.
- `URLEncoder.encode` is marked as deprecated in Netbeans 8. You'll probably want to look into a more forward-compatible alternative:

  ```
  public static String encode(String s, String enc);
  ```
- Strings are hardcoded all over. It's much easier to maintain code when you put all of those type of things in one place.
- You are eating your errors. This is very bad. Errors tell you what is going wrong. When you eat errors you summon the wrath of the Gods; and you will never know when your code isn't working.

Comment: I can't find a url encoder that isn't deprecated. As for thing, it is the "thing" you are storing in dweet, according to the documentation.

Comment: Excess comments are bad too.  You shouldn't use a comment to state what `thing` is, you should name it appropriately.

Comment: I think it's because dweet refers to *that* as a *thing* pretty much extensively on their website... :)